# SharePoint & Visual Studio - Event Handlers - ListItemProperties == NULL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Reference my blog here: http://myspexp.com/2011/06/06/event-receiversits-not-always-as-easy-as-1-2-3/  I am unable to get the properties of the ListItem, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

In ItemAdding, there is no properties.ListItem yet - the item hasn't been saved. To modify what will be saved you have to modify properties.AfterProperties - and that's only for lists, in ItemAdding in a document library the AfterProperties aren't available either.

Check http://www.synergyonline.com/blog/blog-moss/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=25 for more info.

Comment: What do I do if i want to update the item after it has been created?